# The center of a circle is (5,3) and its radius is 4. Which point lies OUTSIDE of the circle? A) (4,2) B) (6,0) C) (4,5) D) (-1,-4)

Tags: geometry

The center of a circle is (5,-3) and its radius is 4. Which point lies OUTSIDE of the circle?

A) (4,-2)
B) (6,0)
C) (4,-5)
D) (-1,-4)

Please show work.

Comment: You first! Show the work, that is.

Comment: Yes, please do.

Answer (score 4):

Given that this circle represents all points such that

$$\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + (y+3)^2} \leq 4,$$

We simply need to find which points do not satisfy this inequality.

A)

$$\sqrt{(4-5)^2 + (-2+3)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 1} = \sqrt{2} \leq 4,$$

and thus it does not lie outside the circle.

B)

$$\sqrt{(6-5)^2 + (0+3)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 9} = \sqrt{10} \leq 4,$$

and thus it does not lie outside the circle.

C) $$\sqrt{(4-5)^2 + (-5+3)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4} = \sqrt{5} \leq 4,$$

and thus it does not lie outside the circle.

D) $$\sqrt{(-1-5)^2 + (-4+3)^2} = \sqrt{36 + 1} = \sqrt{37} > \sqrt{16} = 4,$$

and thus it does lie outside the circle.